# Comparing results of the same survey administered to two different populations. How to call it?

Tags: terminology

For part of my master thesis, I need to conduct a survey targeting academic experts. After evaluating the outcome of the survey, I need to compare the outcome to the outcome of another finished thesis which uses questionnaire targeting practical personnel. Therefore by comparing these two outcomes, the difference or similarities between these two perspectives will be concluded.

Does this kind of method have an academic term?

Comment: This may be a better question for English.SE but I typically hear these referred to as correlation and variance analysis (specific terms vary based on method: mean *correlation* between groups, analysis of *variance* by question/question group, and the like)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about social-science terminology, not academia

Answer (score 2):

The terminology that I would recommend using to describe such a comparison depends on the goal and approach:

- If there is a systematic collection and combination of datasets with the aim of increasing the statistical power of the studies, then it would typically be termed a [meta-analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis).
- Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with simply saying that you are comparing the two studies.